# Как реализовать бесконечный цикл так, чтобы единица двигалась вперед-назад через 8 нулей?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for, while

стоит такая задача:
"Измените приведенный ниже код так, чтобы на экране отображались 8 нулей, а затем 1 бесконечно перемещалась вперед и назад по нулям"

Код, который был дан:

```py
padding = ' ' * 10
while True:
    for i in range(1, 9):
        print(f"{padding}{'1':0>{i}}", end = '\r')
    for j in range(10000000):
        pass
    for i in range(8, 0, -1):
        print(f"{padding}{'0':{8-i}}{'10':>{i}}", end = '\r')
    for j in range(10000000):
        pass
```

Не совсем понимаю, что надо бы изменить в коде для успешного результата. Буду рад любым ответам. Спасибо.

Comment: А питон какой версии? У меня этот код ошибку форматирования даёт.

Comment: @CrazyElf, на 3.10 все ок